# textarea não aceita </script> como texto

Tags: php, javascript

No código abaixo tenho um erro, pois o javascript entende que eu quero fechar a tag script mesmo estando entre aspas. Estou criando um pequeno editor e funciona perfeitamente desde que no texto não tenha `</script>`. Como posso passar `</script>` de forma que o javascript entenda como texto?

```js
echo("<script>window.parent.document.getElementById(\"id_textarea\").value=\"</script>\";</script>");
```

Comment: Tenta colocar barra invertida antes da abertura e fechamento da tag do script,  assim "\</script\>\"

Comment: O ideal para tags é usar `&lt;` para `<` e `&gt;` para `>`. Isso só por si já evita com que seja interpretado como código

Comment: Não resolveu pois aparece &lt no código, e preciso que apareça normalmente,a não ser que eu esteja fazendo algo errado. Obrigado

Answer (score 1):

Esse é um caso bem particular do texto que está a ser colocado na `textarea`. Repare que quando tenta colocar o `</script>` não funciona:

```js
document.getElementById("id_textarea").value="</script>";
console.log("outro código em JS");
```

```html
<textarea id="id_textarea"></textarea>
```

Mas se por acaso for um fecho de um `</div>` já funciona:

```js
document.getElementById("id_textarea").value="</div>";
console.log("outro código em JS");
```

```html
<textarea id="id_textarea"></textarea>
```

Acontece que o próprio interpretador de JS varre o código até apanhar um `</script>` e acaba por encontrar aquele que está como texto, terminando antes do que devia. Consegue resolver facilmente escapando a barra:

```js
document.getElementById("id_textarea").value="<\/script>";
//                                             ^--- escapar a barra
console.log("outro código em JS");
```

```html
<textarea id="id_textarea"></textarea>
```

No seu código, com o PHP ficaria:

```
echo('<script>window.parent.document.getElementById("id_textarea").value="<\/script>";</script>');
```

Note que troquei o inicio do `echo` para aspas simples de forma a simplificar e não ser necessário escapar tanta coisa.

O que eu mencionei como comentário funciona bem se o conteúdo for para ser colocado noutro tipo de etiquetas, como um `<div>` por exemplo.